# How to get boot setup screen in dell inspiron 1545 after switching on?

Tags: boot, dell-inspiron, setup

I am using dell inspiron 1545 laptop. I tried pressing F2 or F12 after switching on x I am not able to view boot setup window. I want to view boot setup config screen.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the laptop, turn it back on, and start tapping <kbd>F12</kbd> before the Dell logo screen appears to bring up the Boot Menu. If that doesn't work, press <kbd>F2</kbd> every few seconds until the message *Entering Setup* appears, and change the boot order in the  BIOS Boot Device Configuration screen so that it goes to the CD-ROM first and the hard drive later.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must prevent *fastboot*, which bypasses UEFI access. To do so, perform a *full shutdown*, rather than the hybrid shutdown of Windows 8/10. Open a CMD prompt, or enter <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and type:

> ```
>   shutdown -f -s -t 00
> ```

2. *Before* you press the power button to restart, *hold down <kbd>F2</kbd>, press the power button while still holding <kbd>F2</kbd> and  and keep it held* until you see the UEFI (BIOS) screen.